# how to bypass the setTimeout throttle in a hidden tab?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm am doing a heavy "scientific" (ie, not displaying data) webgl computation. Webgl can't be put in a worker, and doing a lot of webgl blocks the whole browser so I sliced my computation in chunks, and I compute each chunk in a setTimeout() function (after calling getError() to flush the opengl queue). I leave a bit of time in between the chunks so that the browser has time to flush some UI events from the main UI queue and it makes the whole thing feel a bit less sluggish.

My problem is that when the tab is hidden, the setTimeout gets throttled to a one second period which is way too slow for me.

Is there a better solution than what I did? Obviously requestAnimationFrame() doesn't work, since it's never called back in hidden tabs (and it's too slow in visible).

Is there a non-throttled time event in the hidden state? I tried to use window.postMessage() but it's still too fast and the whole browser feels slow.

here is the current state of my research:

```
            function drawTile(sequenceIndex) {
                if (sequenceIndex < sequence.length) {
                    var x = sequence[sequenceIndex][0];
                    var y = sequence[sequenceIndex][1];
                    setTilePos(x, y);
                    modelStage.render(renderer, modelBuffer);
                    minkowskiPass.render(renderer, minkowskiBuffer, modelBuffer);
                    copyPass.quad.position.x = x;
                    copyPass.quad.position.y = y;
                    copyPass.render(renderer, null, minkowskiBuffer);
                    var gl = renderer.getContext();
                    gl.getError();
                    sequenceIndex++;
                    if (document.visibilityState != "hidden") {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            drawTile(sequenceIndex);
                        }, 10);
                    } else {
                        //window.postMessage is not rate limited then the tab is hidden
                        // we need to slow the computation by an event, otherwise the whole browser is unresponsive.
                        $(window).one('message', function () {
                            drawTile(sequenceIndex);
                        });
                        window.postMessage('lol', '*');
                    }
                } else
                    console.timeEnd('computation');
            }
            console.time('computation');
            drawTile(0);
```

Comment: I have found a convoluted "solution" by putting the setTimeout() in a worker that doesn't seem to be rate limited like the main thread. I'm still open for a simpler system.

Comment: Not really. You cannot force the client to do your computations. What is your actual use case, and what does "too slow" mean?

Comment: The code I posted is straight from my application, what more detail do you want? I'm doing some geometric transformations with webgl. Too slow means the tick rate is not fast enough and it's slowing the global computation.

Comment: You say you do "scientific calculations" that are "not supposed to be used for display". What geometries are you transforming? Why wouldn't you want to do it on the server side? I don't need detail, I want to understand the overall picture.

Comment: I used a 100% percent client route, and the storage is on firebase. I don't want to spend server money on that project for now. Even with a server I would at least need a real time preview when the user changes a parameter in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another convoluted workaround for anyone who needs it; you can use the Web Audio API to generate function calls:

```
var setTimeout2 = (function () {
    var samples = 2048;
    var fns = [];
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    var node = context.createScriptProcessor(samples, 1, 1);

    // This gets fired every ~46 milliseconds. You can change 
    // `samples` to another valid value (256, 512, 1024, 2048,
    // 4096, 8192, or 16384); then it'll get called every 
    // `samples / context.sampleRate` seconds (~46 ms for 
    // `samples == 2048` and `context.sampleRate == 44100`).
    node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
        fns = fns.filter(function (fn) {
            return !fn(Date.now() - fn.t);
        });
    };
    source.connect(node);
    node.connect(context.destination);
    window.do_not_garbage_collect = [context, source, node];

    return function (fn) {
        fn.t = Date.now();
        fns.push(fn);
    };
}());

// Use like this:
setTimeout2(function (t) {
    console.log(t);

    // End after 1 second.
    if (t > 1000)
        return true;  
})
```

Comment: ahah, a friend of mine suggested that too. Crazy minds.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps have a worker thread also run a 
postMessage loop and a fraction of the time (every n iterations), either pause or resume the main thread?